# Mounting /cow on root failed: Invalid argument overlay mount failed

Tags: 18.04

I am using an xps 13 9365, which was data wiped from bios by a friend who then gave it to me thinking it was dead. I tried booting with a USB (current LTS distro (18.04 or similar)) boot disk and got into the language selection / setup menu. By using the F6 option I selected noapic. In bios sata is set to raid and legacy the secure boot option is off.

But when I try to install I get kicked into a tiny font window with the following message

(initramfs) mount: Mounting /cow on root failed: Invalid argument overlay mount failed

Any ideas?

Comment: If you created the USB boot drive with Rufus and selected persistence, you will get such an error with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. It should work if you make a new attempt, this time without selecting persistence. Please let us know if this was the problem, or if it is another problem.

Comment: You can also try the different settings for SATA in the BIOS, maybe AHCI is available and will work better.

Comment: First comment from @sudodus worked for me, installing elementary OS 5 from USB on huawei matebook x pro, from windows 10. I used rufus "with persistence" initially, selecting "no persistence" fixed this issue

Answer (score 18):

Received this error in Ubuntu [Elementary OS] using Rufus 3.8 when selecting persistence. The solution was to create a live USB without persistence, per comment above.

Comment: If you still want a persistent live drive, you can try according to this link: [Persistent live drive with a partition for persistence](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181854/how-is-it-easier-to-make-a-persistent-live-drive-with-ubuntu-19-10)

Comment: I can confirm this. While trying to try Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS via a Live USB drive on an HP ProBook 6470b, I ran into `initramfs mount: mounting /cow on /root failed invalid argument overlay mount failed` at the boot-up of Ubuntu.  This was because I selected persistent storage (8 GB) while flashing Ubuntu using Rufus 3.9.1624.  **Reflashing without persistent storage ("0 size") solved this problem.**  The machine now boots into Ubuntu 18.04.04 LTS.  Now I'm trying to figure out how to get WiFi working but that's a different story ...